# How to display icon file in Adobe Air with HTML/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, air

I have File.icon - bitmap data object. How I can display it in a window with HTML/JavaScript? I have found a suitable example for XML/ActionScript: http://blogs.warwick.ac.uk/stevencarpenter/entry/air_using_native/
I have tried to display it with tag `<object type = "application/x-shockwave-flash">` including `<mx:Image source = "..."/>`. But has received only white rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Either cache it to disk and reload it with a normal HTML img tag or convert the bitmapData to a data URL.

Oh, and you could probably copy the image pixels to an HTML canvas object.